# OpenGL I'm changing my z value but nothing is happening

Tags: c++, opengl

I have an 2D rectangle, and I'm changing it's z component in the vertex shader for all vertices by the same amount k (it's a uniform I control with my arrow keys)

```
#version 330
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos; //vertex shader
layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoord;
out vec3 OurColor;
out vec2 TexCoord;
uniform float k;
void main(){
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z + k, 1.0f);
    TexCoord = aTexCoord;
}
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor; //fragment shader
in vec2 TexCoord;
uniform sampler2D texture1;
uniform sampler2D texture2;
void main(){
    FragColor = mix(texture(texture1, TexCoord), texture(texture2, TexCoord),     0.5);
}
```

Nothing is happening, the rectangle doesn't seem to get farther away or any closer, it only disappears when I make the Z component larger than 1.0 or smaller than -1.0. I tried changing the fourth component and it makes the object smaller and larger like you would expect the Z component to behave.

I tried finding the explanation online but they all use the premade math libraries and noone deals with the underlying mathematics. Can someone please explain how the Z and W behave.

Comment: How do I know if I'm using it? I know what it is and how it works, but I didn't set it to perspective projection either. Maybe the default is set to orthographic?

Comment: @Rabbid76 Projection happens in the vertex shader, so they're in fact not using any projection by the looks of it.

Comment: @InfernoTNT If you change the z coordiante of the geometry only, then you'll see no change in the projection of the geometry on the viewport. (except the geometry is clipped by the near or fare plane). At orthographic projection the geometry is projected in parallel. If the size of the geometry should decrease by distance, then you have to use perspective projection

Comment: @Rabbid76 Alright, so this then means that I have to either change the fourth (w) component to make the object look closer or father away or I have to scale the first and second component (x and y) by some factor to make the object look farther or closer. The former means that third and fourth component (w and z) are completely useless which is quite strange.

Comment: @InfernoTNT Yes, if you want perspective projection, you have to implement it. That means dividing `x` and `y` by `z`.

Comment: @InfernoTNT The common way is to use projection matrix.

Answer (score 1):

The vertex shader is (among other things) supposed to do what the ModelViewProjection matrix did in the fixed-function pipeline: transform the geometry into view coordinates *and project it* into projection coordinates. Which means you should incorporate projection (normally division by `z`) into your vertex shader output.